# Problema al intentar visualizar código html con php

Tags: php, html, sql

Estoy haciendo un sistema de recuperación de contraseña. Al intentar cerrar las llaves al final del documento para que si alguien cambia algún dato de la url no mostrarlo, no me aparece el input para poder cambiar la contraseña, a ver si veis el fallo, por que me estoy volviendo loco.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['token'])){
    require "conexion.php";
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
    $token = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['token']);
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT token FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
    $row = $sql->fetch_array();

    if($row['token'] == $token) { 

?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['codigo'])){
    require "conexion.php";
    $pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $pass = hash('sha512',$pass);

    $act = $mysqli->query("UPDATE usuarios SET pass= '$pass', token = '' WHERE email = '$email'");

    if ($act){
        echo "Su contraseña se ha actualizado correctamente";
        header("Refresh: 1; URL=../index.php");
    }else{
        echo "Ha habido un problema a la hora de actualizar la contraseña";
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nueva contraseña" name="pass" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Cambiar contraseña" name="codigo"/>
</form>
</body>
    <?php }}?>
</html>
```

Comment: Quieres hacer el mismo submit dentro de la misma pagina ?

Comment: Hay una condición para que los inputs se muestren: `if($row['token'] == $token) {`  si eso no se cumple no se mostrarán. ¿Puedes verificar que sí se cumple esa condición?, puedes poner un `else` y sales de dudas.

Comment: El haga lo que haga dice que es igual,es decir, cambie o no el token, al hacer echo pone es igual, nunca se da otra condiciones, no estará cogiendo bien los datos de la tabla?

Comment: No es como dices, **en el código que muestras** el formulario sólo se muestra si esa condición se cumple.

Comment: Pero esa condición no se si se cumple, no se si está recogiendo los datos de la base de datos

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que ninguna etiqueta HTML puede estar dentro una funcion php.
Puedes escribir en el cliente mediante echo si lo deseas o separarlos.Te paso un ejemplo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['token'])){
require "conexion.php";
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$token = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['token']);
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT token FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
$row = $sql->fetch_array();
if($row['token'] == $token) { 
    if(isset($_POST['codigo'])){
        require "conexion.php";
        $pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $pass = hash('sha512',$pass);
        $act = $mysqli->query("UPDATE usuarios SET pass= '$pass', token = '' WHERE email = '$email'");
        if ($act){
            echo "Su contraseña se ha actualizado correctamente";
            header("Refresh: 1; URL=../index.php");
        }else{
            echo "Ha habido un problema a la hora de actualizar la contraseña";
          }
       }
    }    
  } 

     ?>
    <form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Ingrese su nueva contraseña' name='pass' required/>
    <input type='submit' value='Cambiar contraseña' name='codigo'/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Si Quieres dibujar el input desde PHP puedes hacerlo asi.

```
  echo "<form action='' method='post'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Ingrese su nueva contraseña' name='pass' 
   required/>
  <input type='submit' value='Cambiar contraseña' name='codigo'/>
  </form>";
```

Comment: No funciona, ni redirige al intentar cambiar la contraseña, no updatea, ...

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal radica en el lugar donde tienes puesta la validación y la confirmación, más las llaves de cierre de las condiciones.

Al hacer post pierdes las variables del get, porque las recibes cuando cargas la página. Debes incluirlas dentro del formulario para que se envíen a través del post, o en su defecto obtenerlas de otro lugar (base de datos) para añadirlas a la condición que especificaste.

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="??" />
```